# m2e lifecycle-mapping not found

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I am trying to use the solution [described here](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) to solve the annoying "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)" when I place the following plugin on my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>src/bootstrap/java</source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I run mvn clean install I get this:

Reason: POM 'org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

Does anyone have a clue on how to make m2e and maven happy?

Comment: Potential solution for future readers, perhaps not for the original question though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23707050/1590950

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping` plugin doesn't exist actually. It should be used from the `<build><pluginManagement>` section of your `pom.xml`. That way, it's not resolved by Maven but can be read by m2e.

But a more practical solution to your problem would be to install the m2e build-helper connector in eclipse. You can install it from the `Window` > `Preferences` > `Maven` > `Discovery` > `Open Catalog`. That way `build-helper-maven-plugin:add-sources` would be called in eclipse without having you to change your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Having the same issue but not quite sure what is meant by this answer, any chance of an example?

Comment: Does anyone know where one can find "the eclipse connector" for "org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin"?

Comment: I think what he meant is actually build/pluginManagement section, not dependencyManagement.

Comment: that's correct, Hendy, thanks for noticing the error. I edited my answer with the proper info.

Comment: Fred, installing the build-helper connector didn't resolve the original "plugin execution not covered by lifecycle" error. But adding in the PluginManagement config does.

Comment: It's possible the buildhelper connector doesn't support the config you set in you pom.xml. But I'd make sure "Maven > Update project" (after removing the <pluginManagement> config) really doesn't fix the error marker before saying it's broken. 

You should paste here your buildhelper plugin configuration snippet

Comment: @Fred Bricon, i have the exact same issue, but i do have the `org.eclipse.m2e` specification in the `build/pluginManagement` section.  i'm running his goal, trying to deploy my web service to a local tomcat installation as part of the maven build process.  that being said, why would i still have this issue, especially if that snippet was generated by an apache archetype?

Comment: I'd need to see some sample pom to understand what is happening

Comment: What about CI builds?

Comment: plugins defined in build/pluginManagement/plugins are not resolved during CLI builds, only in build/plugins (you can run mvn help:effective-pom to see what plugins are active). So CI builds totally ignore org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping from the pluginManagement section.

Answer (score 11):

Try using the `build/pluginManagement` section, e.g. :

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[2.0.2,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>process</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>                         
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Here's an example to generate bundle manifest during incremental compilation inside Eclipse :

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

versionRange is required, if omitted m2e (as of 1.1.0) will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: Best solution so far. Just adding <pluginManagement> for org.eclipse.m2e below under <build> resolved the said issue

Answer (score 9):

You can use this dummy plugin:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.eclipse.m2e -DartifactId=lifecycle-mapping -Dversion=1.0.0 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-mojo
```

After generating the project install/deploy it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I do it: I put m2e's lifecycle-mapping plugin in a separate profile instead of the default <build> section. the profile is auto-activated during eclipse builds by presence of a m2e property (instead of manual activation in settings.xml or otherwise). this will handle the m2e cases, while command-line maven will simply skip the profile and the m2e lifecycle-mapping plugin without any warnings, and everybody is happy.

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>m2e</id>
      <!-- This profile is only active when the property "m2e.version"
        is set, which is the case when building in Eclipse with m2e. -->
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>m2e.version</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
              <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                  <pluginExecutions>
                    <pluginExecution>
                      <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[0,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>...</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <action>

                        <!-- either <ignore> XOR <execute>,
                          you must remove the other one. -->

                        <!-- execute: tells m2e to run the execution just like command-line maven.
                          from m2e's point of view, this is not recommended, because it is not
                          deterministic and may make your eclipse unresponsive or behave strangely. -->
                        <execute>
                          <!-- runOnIncremental: tells m2e to run the plugin-execution
                            on each auto-build (true) or only on full-build (false). -->
                          <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                        </execute>

                        <!-- ignore: tells m2eclipse to skip the execution. -->
                        <ignore />

                      </action>
                    </pluginExecution>
                  </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: There is absolutly no possibility to configure the lifecycle-mapping plugin for all plugins at once?

Comment: @BlackEye You may add multiple `pluginExecution` entries for different plugins.

Comment: You can generate this boilerplate XML by doing an auto-fix to "Ignore" the Maven error.  Then change <ignore></ignore> to <execute><runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental></execute>

Comment: Thanks for the info on the m2e.version property, couldn't find any documentation on that at all but it seems to work!

Comment: Best answer. No idea about this property either.

Answer (score 9):

m2e 1.7 introduces a [new syntax for lifecycle mapping metadata](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata) that doesn't cause this warning anymore:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>

        <!-- This executes the goal in Eclipse on project import.
             Other options like are available, eg ignore.  -->
        <?m2e execute?>

        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>src/bootstrap/java</source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: **N.B. this syntax will fail to deploy to Sonatypes Maven Central**: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-56004

Answer (score 4):

I have opened a (trivial) bug for this at m2e. Vote for it if you want the warning message to be gone for good...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367870

Answer (score 3):

I was  having the same issue, where:

*No marketplace entries found to handle build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source in Eclipse. Please see Help for more information.*

and clicking the Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > open catalog button would report no connection.

Updating from 7u40 to 7u45 on Centos 6.4 and OSX fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly these 3 steps helped me:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven is trying to download m2e's lifecycle-mapping artifact, which M2E uses to determine how to process plugins within Eclipse (adding source folders, etc.).  For some reason this artifact cannot be downloaded.  Do you have an internet connection?  Can other artifacts be downloaded from repositories?  Proxy settings?

For more details from Maven, try turning M2E debug output on (Settings/Maven/Debug Output checkbox) and it might give you more details as to why it cannot download from the repository.

Comment: That artifact is just missing. I can download other artifacts. Is it gone for good?

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to a missing plugin configuration (as per [vaadin's demo pom.xml](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/pom.xml) comment):

> This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
>   only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e ettings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    vaadin-maven-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>
                                    [7.1.5,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>resources</goal>
                                    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Some how adding `<version>` instead of `<versionRange>` doesn't get propagated to child modules. I had to use `<versionRange>` to get the child modules to behave.

Answer (score 0):

this step works on me : 
1. Remove your project on eclipse
2. Re import project
3. Delete target folder on your project
4. mvn or mvnw install

Comment: Could you please arrange the steps in a proper format and elaborate your answer, this will help others to quickly go through your answer and understand it way better. Thank you :)