# get rid of POM not found warning for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

With intent to get m2e 1.0 working correctly I have had to specify the lifecycle mapping:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.0.2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>process</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>                         
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

But then I get this warning:

```
 [WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
 [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
```

if I run some specific maven task for example `mvn clean install findbugs:findbugs` (If I run only `mvn clean install` then there is no such message)

I know that the problem is that this POM does not exists, because it is only defined to hold the mapping information. ([m2e lifecycle-mapping not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409823/m2e-lifecycle-mapping-not-found))

Anyway, I want to keep my build clean, without any warnings, so how can I get rid of this specific one? (*My CI server checks that there is no warning.*)

I use Maven 3.0.2 and tried Maven 3.0.3 too, but the same result.

Comment: Which Maven version are you running?

Comment: @khmarbaise: It is maven 3.0.2

Comment: Can you post the complete POM of this project...cause i assume that you have a dependency somewhere in your pom...BTW: Have you tried to run this with Maven 3.0.3 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: do you mean an other dependency than the one I have already posted?

Comment: @khmarbaise: it is the same behaviour for Maven 3.0.3

Comment: @khmarbaise: I tyed to add the complete pom, but it is to large. Anyway I guess it is clear where the problem come from, and the warning is correct, but who to get rid of it?

Comment: In contradiction to what you've written it's not clear. Furthermore if your pom is to large things like pastebin.ca exist...Anyway. Have you tried to comment out the whole pluginManagement part with the lifecylce-mapping to check if this is the real cause of your problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I have done the check the other way around: the warning is gone when I remove this plugin. -- And yes the plugin really do not exist, the the warning itself is correct, but for this special plugin it does not matter!

Comment: I have opened a (trivial) bug for this at m2e. Vote for it if you want it fixed.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367870

Comment: Still the same with Maven 3.0.4-RC3.

Comment: @Mirko Friedenhagen: it is not a maven problem, its a problem of lifecycle-mapping plugin.

Comment: Although the update to local nexus solution have been deprecated the artifact build using this link https://github.com/earcam/m2e-stfu and **uploading to nexus** solves the issue.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

My team works around this problem by wrapping the relevant configuration in a profile:

```
<profile>
  <id>only-eclipse</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>m2e.version</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            ...
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: @Ralph Nope, the property activation works because only Eclipse defines the m2e.version property -- it is not activated by vanilla Maven, or in other IDEs. It does assume you are using the M2E Eclipse integration (File > Import > Existing Maven Project) rather than the old eclipse:eclipse goal, though.

Comment: @ctrueden thanks for this - I've ref. it from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367870

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. It fixes the warning, works with current eclipses out of the box and doesn't rely on local repositories or caches, so it works in CI environments as well.

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you very much, i have attached this profile thing at the bottom of my pom.xml (it looks like this: <project>...</project><profile>...</profile>)

Comment: @Hoto It should go inside <profiles> inside <project>—see [the POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles). And [here](https://github.com/scijava/pom-scijava/blob/pom-scijava-7.4.1/pom.xml#L1695-L1801) is a real-world example.

Answer (score 22):

m2eclipse 1.7.0 introduced an alternative, namely an XML processing instruction.

In the original example, you would simply “annotate” every `<execution>` of the `maven-processor-plugin`’s `process` goal with

```
<?m2e execute?>
```

See the [release notes](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata) for more details on the syntax and further options.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer 60 times, it's much neater than the old XML soup

Comment: While the `<profile />` appraoch from @ctrueden is great for all of us that are stuck with older Eclipse-versions - this answer so much!

Comment: Note that the above line marks the plugin for `execution, once, on project import`, which may not be what you want. The next likely option will probably be `<?m2e ignore?>`, which does what it says. There are a few more finely grained options available as well.

Comment: Please can you explain where should I put your code? I can't see any <execution> of the maven-processor-plugin  in the example (and in my pom.xml)

Answer (score 20):

This a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367870) with **WONTFIX** resolution. The suggested solution is the simplest in my opinion:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.eclipse.m2e -DartifactId=lifecycle-mapping \
 -Dversion=1.0.0 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-mojo
```

and `install` this project.

Comment: This worked great.   I added the distributionManagement->repository tag to the pom for our local nexus repo and did a mvn deploy so it fixes it for my team.

Comment: What do you mean with "install this project"? what should I execute?

Comment: @CptWasp the command generates a new project. You need to install it in the local m2 repo with “mvn install”

Answer (score 9):

**This solution is now deprecated, I would recommend using the "profile" solution by @ctrueden which is the accepted answer!**

*While not the most clean solution, when you use a repository manager in your company or are on your own, in the mean time you may do this:
- Checkout https://github.com/mfriedenhagen/dummy-lifecycle-mapping-plugin.
- Run `mvn install` when you are on your own 
- Run `mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=REPO_ID::default::YOUR_THIRDPARTY_REPO_URL` when you have a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory.
- See https://github.com/mfriedenhagen/dummy-lifecycle-mapping-plugin/blob/master/README.creole as well.*

Regards
Mirko

Comment: its a hack, but it is the best solution that I can think of at the moment

Comment: According to your deprecation warning, I change he accept flag, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's now better solution (for the error messages in Eclipse only).

Press <kbd>CTR+1</kbd> on the error *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.1:create-timestamp (execution: default-create-timestamp, phase: validate)* and then select this option:

[image]

This works with `org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml_1.2.0.20120903-1050.jar` plugin (maybe earlier also)

Comment: When you store this in the settings, others will see this again, however. So for companies deploying to a thirdparty repository might be more feasible :-).

Comment: The quick fix you named adds the lifecycle-mapping configuration to the pom. This will *cause* the issue named by the question, not resolve it.

Comment: I agree with @Kissaki; this answer does not address the question being asked here.