# Maven and Jenkins: dependency error when building project

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to move an application from being built locally on a Windows Eclipse installation to a Jenkins server. From what I can see the settings are correct and the dependencies should resolve. Even the ones it is complaining about are there when I check the ~/.m2/repositories/ folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm completely new to Jenkins and little to no experience with Maven itself.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>My-Project</artifactId>
<name>MyProject</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.2.2</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->

    <!-- AspectJ -->

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- CUSTOM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-adapters</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://192.168.1.88:18080/svn/project</connection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>scm:svn:http://192.168.1.88:18080/svn/project</url>
</scm>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>create</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I was originally getting this error:

```
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I've since learned that the m2e:lifecycle-mapping is not a real plugin and is something that's built into Eclipse, so Maven on a Linux server is not able to resolve it. I can manage to to get around it temporarily with this command (courtesy of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409823/m2e-lifecycle-mapping-not-found)):

```
sudo -u jenkins /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.eclipse.m2e -DartifactId=lifecycle-mapping -Dversion=1.0.0 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-mojo
```

But now I'm running into this problem:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building My-Project 1.2.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ My-Project >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (default) @ My-Project ---
[INFO] Change the default 'svn' provider implementation to 'javasvn'.
[INFO] Checking for local modifications: skipped.
[INFO] Updating project files from SCM: skipped.
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 207 at timestamp: 2015-02-13 11:38:15
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: trunk
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ My-Project <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ My-Project ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Using property: groupId = org.eclipse.m2e
[INFO] Using property: artifactId = lifecycle-mapping
[INFO] Using property: version = 1.0.0
[INFO] Using property: package = org.eclipse.m2e
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: org.eclipse.m2e
artifactId: lifecycle-mapping
version: 1.0.0
package: org.eclipse.m2e
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-mojo:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.eclipse.m2e
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: org.eclipse.m2e
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.eclipse.m2e
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: lifecycle-mapping
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.486 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-13T11:38:36-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/137M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project My-Project: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project My-Project: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:211)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

The trick (so far) seems to just add eclipse:eclipse to the command line. So something like this:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

And that's it! After adding that the project builds successfully. This has been a frustrating week with many dents in the wall from my head. Hopefully someone with a similar issue will come across this and find a solution faster than I did. Although I can say now that I have a bit of experience with Jenkins and Maven at this point :P

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered here:

- StackOverflow [get rid of POM not found warning for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905501/get-rid-of-pom-not-found-warning-for-org-eclipse-m2elifecycle-mapping)
- Apache Maven's Jira. There is a patch to fix it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13758
- Eclipse's Bugzilla. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367870

In order to get m2e working correctly:

1. Include the org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping declaration in the pluginManagement section of your pom
2. Associate the declaration to a profile that will activate only inside eclipse. For that the presence of *m2e.version*  variable is checked

```xml
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>only-eclipse</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>m2e.version</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            ...
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score -1):

org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping is not on maven reop

move this plugin from `<build>` to `<pluginManagement>`

this will allow jenkins to skip resolving of non existing plugin

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html