# sonarqube: scan a project from maven: get StringUtils error

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've installed sonarqube on localhost (via docker) and try to scan my maven project with the command below :

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:32768 -Dsonar.login=27948f763e39322e99a8508c38a28385c22b57f8 -e`

But it failed after few seconds :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] User cache: /Users/johann/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-10T10:20:30+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/johann/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

My Java project is working well and sonarqube seems also to be ok.
I will appreciate your help...
Thanks

--
edit
As requested, here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I tried to add the `profile` object as suggested by A J, bu tag is Unrecognised.

And y the way, I'm using intelliJ as IDE.

Thanks

Comment: Is the project you try to analyze building already? (`mvn clean install` being successful).

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency for "lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0" in pom.xml

the error states that ":lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to add the dependency (as described here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.m2e/lifecycle-mapping/1.0.0) but got the an error in the pom.xml ([Java] Missing artifact org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
)

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905501/get-rid-of-pom-not-found-warning-for-org-eclipse-m2elifecycle-mapping

Comment: Also, share your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks, pom.xml added. I also tried to add the profile object in the pom but tag is unrecognised.

Comment: Did you go through the above link?