# How can I organize source-generation in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin which generates sources for my java project and places them into '**target/generated-sources**' folder. I need these sources at compile-time. I want to have them in my project while modifying it, already generated. And of course, I want to put them into the  correct folder under '**src**' folder, and not into '**target/generated-sources**'. How can I organize this using Maven?

In other words, I want to be able:

1. generate sources I need by running some goal of my special source-generating plugin (already done, the sources have the package I specified)
2. move these generated sources to '**src/main/java/...**' folder of standart Maven layout.
3. remove them from '**target/generated-sources**' folder, because otherwise mvn clean install command raises error which says that I have "duplicate class". Indeed, if I just copy generated sources from target to src - I have to classes with the same name and package, though one of them is located in target folder.

Which Maven plugins can hlp with this? I suppose this is a typical task.

Comment: It would be helpful to see relevant configuration of your pom.xml.

Comment: This plugin is developed by you?

Comment: It is not typical, because all generated stuff should go into the target folder. It is easy to clean generated files and also to separate what gets checked in to a source control system.

Comment: The plugin is com4j-maven-plugin. Its places generated files into target/generated-sources folder.

Comment: @Dymytry And this source code from `target/generated-sources` isn't compiled into `target/classes` automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard solution in maven is to generate all source into `target/generated-sources`, all source code from `target/generated-sources` and from `src` is compiled into `target/classes` and merged into target **jar**.

Plugin should never touch files under `src` directory, because these files are managed by version control system (ex. git).

If plugin is badly written and source files from `target/generated-sources` is not automatically compilled into `target`, then use goal `build-helper:add-source` from [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) as @James Kingsbery said.

In [maven-com4j-plugin](https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/maven-com4j-plugin/blob/master/src/com4j/tlbimp/driver/Com4jgenMojo.java) source code there are comments:

```
/**
   * Directory in which to create the Java COM wrapper files. This directory
   * will be added to the Maven project's compile source directory list and
   * will therfore be auto-compiled when the Maven compile phase is run.
   * 
   * @parameter expression="${outputDirectory}"
   *            default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/com4j/java"
   */
```

The more important part and solution to your problem is:

> **This directory
>      will be added to the Maven project's compile source directory list and
>      will therfore be auto-compiled when the Maven compile phase is run**

So, generated source code should be automatically compiled and archived into builded **jar**.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar question w.r.t whether `target/generated-sources` is the standard mechanism not just for annotation processors but for any generated source code. I was wanting for avro plugin generated sources & was able to look at the plugin code as you did to confirm that whatever dir specified via `outputDirectory` param of the plugin is added to the classpath & compiled and packaged. I was also able to see that the default value for this is `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro`. 
Would you mind adding a link to the source for this in where you read this?

Comment: Can you please help share a link to the official maven documentation that mentions this aspect, i.e. that `target/generated-sources` is the standard mechanism not just for annotation processors but for any generated source code? I couldn't see that mentioned both [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html) & [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin works correctly it will add the generated sources to the internal project and other plugins like the maven-compiler-plugin will pick it up and compile the generatd code.

Within your plugin code you can accomplish this by using something similar:

```
mavenProject.addCompileSourceRoot( getOutputDirectory().getAbsolutePath() );
```

Comment: Can you please help share a link to the official maven documentation that mentions this aspect, i.e. that `target/generated-sources` is the standard mechanism not just for annotation processors but for any generated source code?

I couldn't see that mentioned both [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html) & [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [build helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html). It allows you to specify additional source directories (such as target/generated-sources). See also [Usage of maven Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734898/usage-of-maven-build-helper-maven-plugin).