# How to Generate JPA Metamodel classes? (July 2018)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa-2.1

I have a maven/hibernate/mysql app I'm developing and am having an issue getting the jpa-metamodel stuff working. I have this in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764266/generate-the-jpa-metamodel-files-using-maven-processor-plugin-what-is-a-conven) (see 2nd answer down wtih 'March 2018 Answer with Hibernate 5' heading) that addition to the pom.xml and the correct jars on the classpath should be all that are required.

I did a bunch of googling, but most of the answers I came across were old, and I believe deprecated.

Is there a maven goal I need to run especially for the metamodel classes? Does just 'compile' work for these classes?

I also have my compiler settings as follows:

[image]

What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

Comment: checked my compiler settings, which were at 1.5 for some bizarre reason; changed to 1.8 and it worked.