# "Using NULL lifecycle mapping for MavenProject"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lifecycle, m2e

Hello Im working with Eclipse Kepler, but I have working with Hellios a lot of time.

I have a problem with some projects, its very hard to explain but I will try.

Well the problem is: 
You can do a lot of thing under this projects, the result in MAVEN Console is always the same:  [INFO] Using NULL lifecycle mapping for MavenProject.

-I create the "lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml" under the folder C:{myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\, restart eclipse and nothing change.

-I edit the "pom.xml" of the project adding the pluginManagment with lifecycle NOTHING!
-I change the .project and .classpaht of the project.... NOTHING!
-I change my eclipse (Hellios to Kepler)..... NOTHING-

Reading this text maybe you can thing about the problem is the project, but no !  :( 
But here the strange thing, if u create a new MAVEN PROJECT you can see in the MAVEN Console this text: 
[INFO] Using org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: foo.myExample:myExample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:{myWorkspace}\myExample\pom.xml.
Obviously this project is perfect, with a perfect dependencies, etc.

I add the images of my LifeCycling Mapping in the Maven View of Eclipse

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140604060132785641.jpg < wrong project
http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140604060134738146.jpg < good project

I think its something about the project structure, i got :

Project Father ( with pom.xml, with 2 modules) < plugin doestn detect lifeCycle

> Project Son JAR ( with pom.xml) < plugin detect lifeCycle to build a JAR file
>   Project Son WAR ( with pom.xml) < plugin detect lifeCycle to build a WAR file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I start to think its about the project configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [m2e lifecycle-mapping not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409823/m2e-lifecycle-mapping-not-found)