# Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to compile QuickFix engine in Eclipse and encountering "cannot parse lifecycle metadata" error specified below. Does anybody know what M2E might be missing?

I looked through posts, including this but nothing worked so far. 
[m2e lifecycle-mapping not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409823/m2e-lifecycle-mapping-not-found)

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project MavenProject: org.quickfixj:quickfixj-parent:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\quickfix_1.6.0\pom.xml Cause: Duplicated tag: 'pluginExecutionFilter' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n      ... @13:30)  pom.xml /quickfixj-all  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I found is the parser wants

```
   <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
     <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
       ...
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
     </pluginExecution>
    <pluginExecution>
     <pluginExecutionFilter>
      ...
```

Which is fair enough but I don't know how you would know that unless you play around with it until it works like I did so here is a working example. For those of you that can read and understand "documentation" here is the link to some associated gibberish.

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-making-maven-plugins-compat.html

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have duplicate `pluginExecutionFilter` tag

> Cause: Duplicated tag: 'pluginExecutionFilter' (position: START_TAG
>   seen ...\r\n ... @13:30)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your maven cache:

```
Close Eclipse
Delete everything inside .m2/repository
Open Eclipse
Maven Update
```